# calculate the spherical rotation from change in position

Tags: matrices, vectors, rotations

I'm trying to understand how to work the rotation out of the sphere in the gif linked below. Given the spheres Radius, currentMatrix, and a nextPosition Vector, how do I work out the sphere's newMatrix?

Does any one have any ideas?
I've tried googling a bunch of stuff but I'm not really sure if I've found the right equation of formula to work this out. Any guidance would be really appreciated

[image]

**Input:**
Sphere Radius

Sphere currentMatrix

**Move around:**
nextPosition Vector

**Output:**
Sphere newMatrix

Comment: What is a sphere's matrix? It doesn't make much sense to assign a matrix to a state of an object

Comment: If this is what I think, the new matrix is not unique. If this is not what I think, then blame yourself for not explaining anything.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/bcdFYcH)
This is all the information I can get from this, I'm just trying to understand the math behind it, that's all. Sorry if I explained it in correctly, I blame myself truly

Comment: @Couchy311 It’s common in computer graphics to have a matrix attached to each object that transforms between world coordinates and local object model coordinates. The object can be rotated, scaled &c via this matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by `sphereMatrix` you mean the 3×3 orientation matrix describing the local to global transformation matrix.

In general a body with rotational velocity **ω**=`(ωx,ωy,ωz)` and orientation matrix **R** will update the orientation matrix after some time Δt by converting the rotational velocity into an axis of rotation and a small angle of rotation.

So you have **R**' = **Rot**(**k**, Δθ)***R**

What is the rotation axis **k**? Take the direction of **ω** with **k**=**ω**/`mag(`**ω**`)` and the small angle Δθ=`mag(`**ω**`)`*Δt.

Lastly look up the [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) to conver the axis angle into a 3×3 rotation matrix.

In the video the rotation matrix is found by the no-slip condition on the contact of the sphere with the floor. From rigid body mechanics it is found that

**ω** = `[vy/R,0,-vx/R]`

if `R` is the radius of the sphere, +*y* is the "up" direction and `vx`, `vy` are the velocity components of the center of the sphere along the *x* and *y* directions.